# What is the correct way to use Ajax for editing table rows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I looked through a number of posts with similar titles but have not found an answer.

In my application I want to allow editing Active records from an index view. This view uses  link_to_remote for each row. When user presses the link the row should be replaced with a form that user may submit via Ajax.

Table is displayed by sending a collection to show_item partial

```
<% content_tag_for(:tr, show_item) do %>
<td><%=h show_item.name %> </td>
<td><%= show_item.role %></td>
<td><%= link_to_remote 'Edit', :url => edit_participation_path(show_item), :method => :get %> </td>
<% end %>
```

My controller implements editing as

```
   def edit
     @participation = Participation.find(params[:id])
     respond_to do |format|
       format.js do
         render(:update) { |page| page[@participation].replace_html(:partial => "edit_item", :object => @participation ) }
       end
     end
    end
```

Edit_item partial looks like

```
<% content_tag_for(:tr, edit_item) do %>
  <% form_remote_for edit_item do |f| %>
     <td><%= edit_item.name %></td>
     <td> <%= f.select(:role, options_for_select(all_roles, edit_item.role)) %> </td>
     <td><%= submit_tag 'Update', :class => 'submit' %></td>
     <td><%= link_to_remote 'Cancel', :url => participation_path(edit_item) %></td>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Remote calls do go through but they affect the table in an unexpected way. In Firefox pressing the link causes the row to disappear. On the other hand if I use Safari the row is updated but instead of aligning cells with other table rows the entire replaced row is placed to the left of other rows.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is a syntax error in the html. I notice you have 4 td tags in your edit partial, but only 3 in the show partial. You may want to view the generated source from Firebug and validate it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any template? when you use link_to_remote it loads the result with a template if you are using one.

Check the source code using firebug addon and confirm if the code in the result is exactly what you want.

Comment: I intended to have 4 tds in the result and only 3 in original. Besides making both have the same 4 tds, does not make a difference as far as the problem ids concerned. I am not using a template. My controller renders everything in-line. Firebug shows that response was received but had a code 304 which I guess indicates that I made no modifications to the database (as intended).

Comment: 304 indicates you that the page you have in the client is exactly the same as the last recieved in previos requests. I mean, did you checked the source, the html, and it is correct?